# Change fileshare root in Excel dynamically by modifying the xml behind the Excel with Python

Tags: python, excel, xml

We are at a point of a fileshare migration but a lot of excel files on the current share reference each other including roots (in formulas).
I figured it's possible to change the formula references of the current root to the new root by modifying the underlying xml.

I did modify one tag value of the XML, hoping that the structure of the XML would stay the same. However unfortunately the structure doesn't stay the same.

Tag: `<x15ac:absPath xmlns:x15ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/ac" url="Q:\General\Results\2021\"`

should be modified to `<x15ac:absPath xmlns:x15ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/ac" url="I:\Results\2021\"`

As you can see the structure and tags changes and I can't come up with the reason for that.
Appreciate your help on solving this. Please let me know if I need to clarify.

My python code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Change workbook.xml
tree = ET.parse('workbook.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for elem in root.iter():
    if str(elem.get('url'))[:11] == 'Q:\General':
        elem.set('url', elem.get('url').replace(r'Q:\General', 'I:\Results'))
tree.write('workbook.xml', encoding='UTF-8', method='xml',  xml_declaration=True)
```

XML of initial excel file (workbook.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<workbook
    xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"
    xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="x15 xr xr6 xr10 xr2"
    xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main"
    xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision"
    xmlns:xr6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision6"
    xmlns:xr10="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision10"
    xmlns:xr2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/revision2">
    <fileVersion appName="xl" lastEdited="7" lowestEdited="7" rupBuild="23426"/>
    <workbookPr defaultThemeVersion="166925"/>
    <mc:AlternateContent
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
        <mc:Choice Requires="x15">
            <x15ac:absPath url="Q:\General\Results\2021\"
                xmlns:x15ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/ac"/>
            </mc:Choice>
        </mc:AlternateContent>
        <xr:revisionPtr revIDLastSave="0" documentId="13_ncr:1_{77E8B687-2130-4B59-8784-F53BD3BD2847}" xr6:coauthVersionLast="45" xr6:coauthVersionMax="45" xr10:uidLastSave="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"/>
        <bookViews>
            <workbookView xWindow="28680" yWindow="-120" windowWidth="29040" windowHeight="15990" xr2:uid="{00000000-000D-0000-FFFF-FFFF00000000}"/>
        </bookViews>
        <sheets>
            <sheet name="Blad1" sheetId="1" r:id="rId1"/>
        </sheets>
        <calcPr calcId="191029"/>
        <extLst>
            <ext uri="{140A7094-0E35-4892-8432-C4D2E57EDEB5}"
                xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main">
                <x15:workbookPr chartTrackingRefBase="1"/>
            </ext>
            <ext uri="{B58B0392-4F1F-4190-BB64-5DF3571DCE5F}"
                xmlns:xcalcf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2018/calcfeatures">
                <xcalcf:calcFeatures>
                    <xcalcf:feature name="microsoft.com:RD"/>
                    <xcalcf:feature name="microsoft.com:Single"/>
                    <xcalcf:feature name="microsoft.com:FV"/>
                    <xcalcf:feature name="microsoft.com:CNMTM"/>
                    <xcalcf:feature name="microsoft.com:LET_WF"/>
                </xcalcf:calcFeatures>
            </ext>
        </extLst>
    </workbook>
```

Output XML after python code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns0:workbook
    xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"
    xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/ac"
    xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision"
    xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision6"
    xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision10"
    xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/revision2"
    xmlns:ns7="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
    xmlns:ns8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main"
    xmlns:ns9="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2018/calcfeatures" ns1:Ignorable="x15 xr xr6 xr10 xr2">
    <ns0:fileVersion appName="xl" lastEdited="7" lowestEdited="7" rupBuild="23426" />
    <ns0:workbookPr defaultThemeVersion="166925" />
    <ns1:AlternateContent>
        <ns1:Choice Requires="x15">
            <ns2:absPath url="I:\Results\2021\" />
        </ns1:Choice>
    </ns1:AlternateContent>
    <ns3:revisionPtr revIDLastSave="0" documentId="13_ncr:1_{77E8B687-2130-4B59-8784-F53BD3BD2847}" ns4:coauthVersionLast="45" ns4:coauthVersionMax="45" ns5:uidLastSave="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <ns0:bookViews>
        <ns0:workbookView xWindow="28680" yWindow="-120" windowWidth="29040" windowHeight="15990" ns6:uid="{00000000-000D-0000-FFFF-FFFF00000000}" />
    </ns0:bookViews>
    <ns0:sheets>
        <ns0:sheet name="Blad1" sheetId="1" ns7:id="rId1" />
    </ns0:sheets>
    <ns0:calcPr calcId="191029" />
    <ns0:extLst>
        <ns0:ext uri="{140A7094-0E35-4892-8432-C4D2E57EDEB5}">
            <ns8:workbookPr chartTrackingRefBase="1" />
        </ns0:ext>
        <ns0:ext uri="{B58B0392-4F1F-4190-BB64-5DF3571DCE5F}">
            <ns9:calcFeatures>
                <ns9:feature name="microsoft.com:RD" />
                <ns9:feature name="microsoft.com:Single" />
                <ns9:feature name="microsoft.com:FV" />
                <ns9:feature name="microsoft.com:CNMTM" />
                <ns9:feature name="microsoft.com:LET_WF" />
            </ns9:calcFeatures>
        </ns0:ext>
    </ns0:extLst>
</ns0:workbook>
```

Comment: Relationships between files are stored in a few different places (e.g. look for "rels" file). Microsoft has an [OpenXML SDK for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk). It's for C# and I wasn't able to find any Python wrapper, but it could still be a good starting point to learn what you need to update

Comment: Is there a way to keep the structure of the XML and only change the element that I need to change? If I do this manually it works out like a charm..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a simple change, I would not bother with the overhead of an XML parser.

The code in this example works and will not modify your XML files in unexpected ways.

First, open the file in read-mode, create a string variable to hold the modified output, and then close the read-only file handle.

```
workbook = open('workbook.xml', 'r')
fix_workbook = workbook.read()
fix_workbook = fix_workbook.replace("<x15ac:absPath url=\"Q:\\General\\Results\\2021\\", "<x15ac:absPath url=\"I:\\Results\\2021\\")
workbook.close()
```

Reopen the file in write mode, save the change, and close the file handle.

```
workbook = open('workbook.xml', 'w')
workbook.write(fix_workbook)
workbook.close()
```

That's it!

Extra credit: Picking the right tool for the job can be tricky. Python is great in many ways, but there are sharper tools in the toolbox for this simple task. Here is a comprehensive list of [ways to replace strings in text files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files) using the UNIX command-line tools at Stack Exchange.